# Replacing fields matching a pattern with awk

Tags: awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
7846 1 8.89279e-05 0.094563 0.760024 1 0 0 0 0 0
6843 6 0.0170262 1.44256e-05 0.903887 2 -7 -8 0 0 -12.3666
4583 1 0.929271 0.586333 5.99739e-05 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

And I want to convert the scientific notation in $3, $4, and $5 to zero.

```
7846 1 0.000000 0.094563 0.760024 1 0 0 0 0 0
6843 6 0.0170262 0.000000 0.903887 2 -7 -8 0 0 -12.3666
4583 1 0.929271 0.586333 0.000000 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I am new to awk, but I know I can match fields for the specified pattern like this:

```
awk '$3 ~ /e-0/' test.dat
```

But I do not know how to replace the field.

Thanks,  know this is an easy question, but I couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /[0-9]+e/){match($i,/[^.]*/);val=RLENGTH;match($i,/\.[^e]*/);$i=sprintf("%0"val"d.%0"RLENGTH"d",$i,$i)}}} 1'   Input_file
```

OR

```
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i ~ /[0-9]+e/){
       match($i,/[^.]*/);
       val=RLENGTH;
       match($i,/\.[^e]*/);
       $i=sprintf("%0"val"d.%0"RLENGTH"d",$i,$i)}}
}
1'   Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This worked for me: awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /e-0/){$i = "0.000000"}}print}

Comment: @AdamBarnett, it will be like hard coding, which is why I haven't done this, if you always want to have same number of zeros then you could use it then.